# Rails Google Custom Search API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, search, rubygems

Is there a gem for Rails to do a google custom search? Where can I find an example of a google custom search? On google's website the custom search API is deprecated, would that also apply to a ruby gem?

Answer (score 0):

I found those two: https://github.com/vodafon/google_cse
https://github.com/alexreisner/google_custom_search

But it seems that to use the API for big sites you need a paid account.